# Java JDK Installation

Tags: java

OK, what am I doing wrong, this is driving me nuts.

I am trying to install the latest JDK (1.6.0_23).  So, I downloaded it from Oracle's awful site and then ran the installation.  I installed it to C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23

Then, I created a JAVA_HOME User Variable that pointed to C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23.  I then added a piece to the end of my Path environment variable that says %JAVA_HOME%\bin.

However, when I try to simply open a command prompt and run simple java commands, I am told it is not a recognizable command.  I have to manually cd into the that bin directory to do anything.

Do I also need a Classpath variable that points to the JRE?  I noticed there was a Classpath variable there previously that pointed to jre/lib/QTJava.zip, but I deleted it.

If you have the JDK installed and a JAVA_HOME variable setup, do I still need the JRE in the classpath?  I am running Windows 7 and do all of my development in Eclipse.

Comment: Show us **exactly** what the environment variable is set to.  Your description is ambiguous.

Comment: JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23       this is the user variable

Comment: Path=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\android-sdk_r05-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is because you set JAVA_HOME as a user variable, but trying to reference it from the PATH which is a system variable (or is it?). You cannot do this, because system variables are evaluated before user variables.

There are two possible solutions:
 1. Set JAVA_HOME as a system variable instead
 2. Create a new user variable PATH and set %JAVA_HOME%\bin there. The user PATH and the system PATH variables will be concatenated at runtime automatically.

Comment: Adding to this, an obvious suggestion I haven't seen mentioned explicitly is to type `echo %PATH%` in cmd. Everything should be expanded. My guess is that the variable `%JAVA_HOME%` did not resolve properly. Also note that if you use `set` in cmd, my experience is that this does not persist across multiple instances of cmd, so instead you should do the Control Panel option (or right-click (My) Computer, etc.). There you can set `%JAVA_HOME%` so that it is on the same level as `%PATH%`. Also one more obvious suggestion: After making changes, try closing your cmd and opening a new one.

Comment: Yeah, I had to set JAVA_HOME as a system variable instead of user variable.  Then, I could use %JAVA_HOME% references.  Defining it in User vars then trying to use it in Environment variables does not work as rodion said above.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

From http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistainstall/thread/48b23109-9fbc-47c5-a5d1-465773f94704

(at the end)

> 1) Enable 'delayed variable expansion'
>   in the registry (see
>   http://batcheero.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-enabledelayedexpansion.html)
>
> 2) Change the '%' signs around var2 to
>   '!', e.g. "%var2%" becomes "!var2!"
>
> I've done some limited testing on
>   Windows 7 and this appears to fix the
>   problem.

Maybe try that, see if it fixes it (I don't have windows here to try)

Answer (score 1):

> Do I also need a CLASSPATH variable that points to the JRE?

Strictly speaking, no.  The CLASSPATH variable may be used if you try to run a java class and you don't use the -cp or -jar options.

The CLASSPATH variable doesn't need to point to the JRE.  The `java.exe` command etc all know where to find the JRE's runtime classes.  (And they don't look on the CLASSPATH for them anyway.)

For the PATH problem, try running:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\java.exe -version
```

If that doesn't work then there's a problem with your actual installation.  If it does work, try looking at what JAVA_HOME and PATH are set to *in the environment variables of the command shell*.